# Piano 2 notes at the same time

Tags: piano, sheet-music

[image]

How the flip do you play these 2 keys at the same time? Is it like that you hold it with another finger, or acts kinda like a ghost note?

Comment: Are you asking about the C in the right hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this double-note and how do you play it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/what-is-this-double-note-and-how-do-you-play-it) and various other almost identical questions

Answer (score 5):

I assume you ask about the c' in the right hand.

You would hold the whole note/ semibreve for four beats (*e.g.* with your thumb) while playing the quarter notes (g', e' flat etc.)

You're probably wondering, what to do about the the c' quarter note/crotchet, and if it's redundant then.

You don't  hit the c' key a second time or similar. However, it's written to highlight the melody in that piece.

This piece has two voices in the treble clef. The lower voice consists of the whole note c' (1st bar) and d' (2nd bar). The second voice consists of the quarter notes c', g', e' flat, g' (tied), etc.

Two make both melodies clearly visible, the c' of both voices is written, although you hit the key only once.