# Notes don't add up to time signature

Tags: notation, rhythm

I'm a complete noob when it comes to sheet music and I have a (probably) very stupid question regarding this:[image]

The way I see it, the notes and pause don't add upp to 4 beats? First a dotted quarter, 3/8ths of the bar, then an eighth pause, 4/8ths, then an eighth note, 5/8ths, followed by half notes, 9/8ths?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two adjacent notes of same pitch seemingly occupying the same beat?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61200/two-adjacent-notes-of-same-pitch-seemingly-occupying-the-same-beat)

Comment: @guidot Not really.

Comment: It is not a stupid question but there are plenty of sources from you can get an answer quicker, e.g. searching "dotted quarter note"

Answer (score 31):

The dot above the quarter note is a staccato articulation which doesn't affect its rhythmic value. It's still a quarter note. If the dot was to the right of the note it would change its rhythmic value.

The sample has two voices. The top voice (sticks upwards) has a half note rest followed by a half note.

The lower voice (sticks downwards) has a staccato quarter note followed by an eighth note rest then an eighth note tied into the following half note. The eighth note rest is vertically misaligned - it should be further up the staff.

Comment: I think the eighth rest is further down the staff to indicate that it corresponds to the lower voice. But it's so far down, and the lower voice in such a high register, that it's more confusing than helpful in this particular situation.

Comment: I'd agree with @Kevin that the eighth rest should have been placed somewhere around the 2nd or third staff line.