# How would I play this note that has two G’s next to each other

Tags: piano, sheet-music

How would I play the notes that are side by side in the same line?

[image: score snippet]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this note have a stem pointing up and another pointing down?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/why-does-this-note-have-a-stem-pointing-up-and-another-pointing-down)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two adjacent notes of same pitch seemingly occupying the same beat?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61200/two-adjacent-notes-of-same-pitch-seemingly-occupying-the-same-beat)

Answer (score 3):

You'd play the G and hold it for the bar. It's the same note played in two different voices. There have been many similar questions concerning this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

As far as playing is concerned, **play the notes once and hold it for the largest of the two time values** given.

This kind of writing is done when the music is for more no. of voices than staves used. Within a staff, if there are two voices, first voice's note stem goes up and the other voice's goes down. When writing for two voices, time signature has to be satisfied for both voices seperately and independently.

Note that this kind of question has been asked several time is MusSE and make sure you do your research before asking a question. Duplicate questions get closed.