# Playing multiple notes with different duration on the same key simultaneously?

Tags: piano, fingering

My son wanted to learn the Wellerman song on piano, so I looked up a sheet on MuseScore which I thought he could do, but is still a bit of a challenge. Now I have some trouble understanding it myself.

The sheet contains some notes which seemingly shall be played while the same note is already played.

[image: Wellerman song score]

How shall I deal with those? And: is there a more correct notation to describe the same intent? How would that look like?

Until now I have played the right hand only, in which case I let the long note stop when needed in order to achieve the melody required for the text. I would do the same for the left hand as well, but I thought I'd better ask - maybe there is another way of playing it that I can't come up with.

Comment: In the linked question, see in particular [Raskolnikov's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/4686/70803), which describes the technique to use.

Comment: By the way, you can surely find a better arrangement of such a popular tune. The choices around the voicing of chords in this one seem bizarre to the point of arbitrary, and unnecessarily difficult to play.